# How to use Moq.MockRepository.Of() method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

What is the proper use of Moq.MockRepository.Of() and Moq.MockRepository.OneOf()?
I've tried something like this to try to figure it out.

```
var mr = new MockRepository(MockBehavior.Strict);
var m = mr.Of<ISomeInterface>();
foreach (var obj in m)
    cnt++;
```

I've found that cnt just keeps incrementing to no end.  What gives?  Documentation regarding this is not forthcoming.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `Moq.MockRepository.Of()` to create mocks via expressions. This is best explained by an example:

```
public interface ITest
{
    String Say();
    Int32 DoSomething(Int32 a, Int32 b);
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var repo = new MockRepository(MockBehavior.Strict);
        var mock = repo.Of<ITest>()
                       .Where(s => s.Say() == "Hi!")
                       .Where(s => s.DoSomething(5, 4) == 20)
                       .Where(s => s.DoSomething(4, 5) == 9)
                       .Where(s => s.DoSomething(It.IsAny<Int32>(), 7) == 99)
                       .First();

        Console.WriteLine(mock.Say());                 // prints Hi!
        Console.WriteLine(mock.DoSomething(5, 4));     // prints 20
        Console.WriteLine(mock.DoSomething(4, 5));     // prints 9
        Console.WriteLine(mock.DoSomething(23423, 7)); // prints 99
        Console.WriteLine(mock.DoSomething(0, 0));     // Fail due to MockBehavior.Strict

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having difficulty getting a configured instance of the 'ITest' mock. The sample code works as-is, but otherwise acquiring the 'mock' instance results in `MockException: All invocations of the mock must have a corresponding setup.`

`var mock = repo.Create<ITest>().Object;`

or

`var mock = repo.Of<ITest>().First();`

I presume I'm doing something wrong?